# Tricky NullPointerException

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, boolean

For my Computer Science course, we're making a program that simulates a vending machine business. Everything seems not to have any errors, but then this line in the driver runs,

```
VendingMachine pv0001 = new SnackMachine(19.00); 
pv0001.addItem(new Chips("Doritos"));
```

it returns this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SnackMachine.addItem(SnackMachine.java:35)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:9)
```

Which is apparently stemming from the declaration of this if statement the `SnackMachine` code:

```
public boolean addItem(VendingMachineItem item)
    {
       if((item instanceof Snack) && (inventory.size() < maxCapacity))//error on this line
       {
           inventory.add(item);
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, can anybody help me?

Comment: What is `inventory`? Show us where it is declared.

Comment: Why not use a debugger, or if you don't have one, insert println statements to dump out the values ahead of that statement.  Assuming you've identified the line correctly, most likely `inventory` is null.

Comment: As a matter of habit, I highly recommend prefixing any instance variables you reference with `this.`. That makes it obvious with variables are instance variables, and it lowers the risk of bugs due to shadowing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized `inventory`?

Comment: Would I initialize inventory in the SnackMachine class, or in the VendingMachine class that it extends?

Comment: @Ziggy Probably VendingMachine assuming it defined the original variable, although SnackMachine might replace the value in its constructor as well if it has some reason to. (I can't think of a reason it might, though.) Regardless, you have to initialize it *somewhere* before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `inventory` is initialised when your `VendingMachine` object is initialised.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointer Exception occurs when you declare a variable but did not create an object, therefore it points to null. To avoid this type of exception check for null, if you did not create the object your self.

```
public boolean addItem(VendingMachineItem item)
    { if( item == null )System.out.println("Item passed in must equal to null."); }
```

Inventory also doesn't seem to be declared, i'm assuming you must have it as a global variable, if not this may also as well be causing issues.